# Unable to push origin on public repo 2fa

Tags: git, github, git-push, github-for-mac

I am trying to update the following repository https://github.com/ilyas-it83/CloudComparer

I cloned it, done some updates to the file and now I try to push it for a new pull request.

I am using 2FA on my github account so after stackoverflowing I generated access key.

Here is my github version

```
git version 2.19.1
```

Here is my loca git config

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://wojciehm@github.com/ilyas-it83/CloudComparer.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[credential]
    username = wojciehm
```

I tried to change url to ssh://blah, but it didn't work.

Here is the error I receive.

```
git push origin add-wojciech-marusiak
Password for 'https://wojciehm@github.com':
remote: Permission to ilyas-it83/CloudComparer.git denied to wojciehm.
fatal: unable to access 'https://wojciehm@github.com/ilyas-it83/CloudComparer.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: You probably didn't _create your own fork_ and are pushing to a project you're not allowed to (403). Start here: https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/

Comment: That was it. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you own the repository or are you trying to submit a PR to someone elses?

Sounds like this is just [someone else's repo you're trying to make a PR onto](https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/).

If that's the case you need to fork the repo, which you can do on the repos page (https://github.com/ilyas-it83/CloudComparer).

Then once you make the changes, click on pull requests and then new pull request and select your forked repo.

Comment: I had started writing a more detailed "how to use a token" answer when it occurred to me that it's irrelevant, because this is *almost certainly* the problem.

Comment: That was it. Sorry for lame question. This was my first attempt to contribute to someone else repository. New pull is created :)

Comment: @wojcieh Not lame; everyone needs to start somewhere!